# node.js - express - URL and error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'm new to node.js, so please be indulgently.

I'm just playing around with node.js and the express-module.
I had an idea how to deal with browser-requests and now i have a simple question:

Is this a good idea/practice or is there a better solution to handle that?

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(80);

app.get('/*',function(req,res,next){
    fs.exists(__dirname + req.url, function (exists) {
        if(exists)
        {
            console.log('Sending ' + __dirname + req.url + "...");
            res.sendfile(__dirname + req.url);      
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(__dirname + req.url + " not found!");
            res.send('Sorry, page not found.',404);     
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express is based on [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) and as such supports its middleware. And there is a perfect middleware for your situation: [static file serving](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html).

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This will serve all files within the `/public` directory as static files available from the root directory. For routes which are not handled separately and for which no file exists, a 404 error is returned.

Btw. you want to put the `listen`-call to the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped me a lot. Is there any documentation for express, or for node-modules in general?

Comment: Yes, see the [express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) and the [API reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html) and of course the [connect documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) for a full overview. And then you can always check the source for the projects.